# Extract all strings in between between all same pairs of the two string using regex or python functions

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex or python functions to extract all the bolded texts, or texts in between ' and <=.

> "[Text(447.1153846153846, 471.625, '**the** <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.97\nsamples = 100.0%\nvalue = [0.399, 0.601]\nclass = True News'), Text(238.46153846153845, 336.875, '**donald** <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.921\nsamples = 83.7%\nvalue = [0.336, 0.664]\nclass = True News'), Text(119.23076923076923, 202.125, '**hillary** <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.981\nsamples = 55.6%\nvalue = [0.42, 0.58]\nclass = True News'), Text(59.61538461538461, 67.375, '\n  (...)  \n'), Text(178.84615384615384, 67.375, '\n  (...)  \n'), Text(357.6923076923077, 202.125, '**hillary** <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.663\nsamples = 28.2%\nvalue = [0.172, 0.828]\nclass = True News'), Text(298.0769230769231, 67.375, '\n  (...)  \n'), Text(417.30769230769226, 67.375, '\n  (...)  \n'), Text(655.7692307692307, 336.875, '**trumps** <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.859\nsamples = 16.3%\nvalue = [0.718, 0.282]\nclass = Fake News'), Text(596.1538461538462, 202.125, '**hillary** <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.821\nsamples = 15.7%\nvalue = [0.744, 0.256]\nclass = Fake News'), Text(536.5384615384615, 67.375, '\n  (...)  \n'), Text(655.7692307692307, 67.375, '\n  (...)  \n'), Text(715.3846153846154, 202.125, 'entropy = 0.0\nsamples = 0.6%\nvalue = [0.0, 1.0]\nclass = True News')]"

So far the closest I got was (?=')(.*)(?= <=), but had no luck so far.

Would anyone let me know how to extract these bolded texts in between single quote and <=?

Does not necessary need to be using regex.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify, are the bolded texts bolded by you for emphasis in this example, or are they actually markdown formatted like `**text**`? If they're markdown, you need to also account for the asterisks that create the bolding: `(?<=')(\*{2}\w*\*{2})(?<!<=)` should do the trick.

Comment: What about `", '.*?<="`?

Comment: The bolded texts are bolded by me for emphasis. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: My bad, I misread the `entropy` one.

Comment: I do not think so. Because no entropy is between single quotes and smaller or equal to sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lookarounds, short and working:

```py
re.findall(r"'(\w+)\s*<=", s)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/W8YGGF/1) | [Python proof](https://tio.run/##lZM9b8IwEEB3foUVqSJpo5M/z44Ea8dObIQhKqlADSZyQim/Pk1SIRyKAl0sWb7zvXc@l6d6s7fClK5ptrty72ri8klF5iRYLvLvOpRSA2NKGIm/a0ykZoBcxWRab3IymxMKKrW5rd2@PJFum@jUVtmuLPLuJkYp0KfUfmXFIW/3SwoiSeI2Dilbpfa9yKoubuHa47f8WE2jmPTFuTBwrtuvbVEhEIzuqq/3NivWtwE48wmMAH0FILAHQDkKwFgCXFCNyXmNCaccWK@/2RZF5k63CcyAQCnAIYHkHYAyo/VVAr4@spigBtHrp5aEABCR1F54tQEz6NidBKE0XOSo1o/6IQrfjxvgQz@me0HDxw15YsDv7z1DydpTL4HjnQRsW699RX@EanfYldVNQaOSwRAjiKGgZqYT5IZ7gq/Z558nRPCfkD/aYTOcYaauZ1hL2QMoHAdobf0RUv9v2Gi8bsn866Uv6AtRX4de/wcaEwb09qysgknptrYOXQ4fW7vOiiJ0wTRMjy9RWj3P5kFMqihqmh8).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <=                       '<='
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works. We use a named group so it is easy to refer to the exact data you want. It's setup to find consecutive words, and digits followed by " <=". We then use `finditer` to get all of the matches.

```
import re

data = "[Text(447.1153846153846, 471.625, 'the <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.97\nsamples = 100.0%\nvalue = [0.399, 0.601]\nclass = True News'), Text(238.46153846153845, 336.875, 'donald <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.921\nsamples = 83.7%\nvalue = [0.336, 0.664]\nclass = True News'), Text(119.23076923076923, 202.125, 'hillary <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.981\nsamples = 55.6%\nvalue = [0.42, 0.58]\nclass = True News'), Text(59.61538461538461, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(178.84615384615384, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(357.6923076923077, 202.125, 'hillary <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.663\nsamples = 28.2%\nvalue = [0.172, 0.828]\nclass = True News'), Text(298.0769230769231, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(417.30769230769226, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(655.7692307692307, 336.875, 'trumps <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.859\nsamples = 16.3%\nvalue = [0.718, 0.282]\nclass = Fake News'), Text(596.1538461538462, 202.125, 'hillary <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.821\nsamples = 15.7%\nvalue = [0.744, 0.256]\nclass = Fake News'), Text(536.5384615384615, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(655.7692307692307, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(715.3846153846154, 202.125, 'entropy = 0.0\nsamples = 0.6%\nvalue = [0.0, 1.0]\nclass = True News')]"

fmt = re.compile(r'(?P<info>[\w\d]+) <=', re.I)
for m in fmt.finditer(data):
    print(m.group('info'))
```

If you just want to go the whole 9 yards, the below will parse the entire thing into a named tuple that primarily mirrors the format of the text. I didn't know what the first 2 values represent so, I just called them `x` and `y`. I went this far because what you want doesn't seem very useful, and I assume this question is just a precursor to eventually pinpointing more data. This pinpoints all of the data. Any entry with `\n (...) \n` data is printed as being "empty", and is not stored in the entries `list`.

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

data    = "[Text(447.1153846153846, 471.625, 'the <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.97\nsamples = 100.0%\nvalue = [0.399, 0.601]\nclass = True News'), Text(238.46153846153845, 336.875, 'donald <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.921\nsamples = 83.7%\nvalue = [0.336, 0.664]\nclass = True News'), Text(119.23076923076923, 202.125, 'hillary <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.981\nsamples = 55.6%\nvalue = [0.42, 0.58]\nclass = True News'), Text(59.61538461538461, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(178.84615384615384, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(357.6923076923077, 202.125, 'hillary <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.663\nsamples = 28.2%\nvalue = [0.172, 0.828]\nclass = True News'), Text(298.0769230769231, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(417.30769230769226, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(655.7692307692307, 336.875, 'trumps <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.859\nsamples = 16.3%\nvalue = [0.718, 0.282]\nclass = Fake News'), Text(596.1538461538462, 202.125, 'hillary <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.821\nsamples = 15.7%\nvalue = [0.744, 0.256]\nclass = Fake News'), Text(536.5384615384615, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(655.7692307692307, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(715.3846153846154, 202.125, 'entropy = 0.0\nsamples = 0.6%\nvalue = [0.0, 1.0]\nclass = True News')]"

#regex to describe the overall entry
entfmt  = re.compile(r'Text\((?P<x>([\d\.]+)), (?P<y>([\d\.]+)), \'(?P<data>([^\']+))\'\)', re.I|re.S)

#format all of the float groups ~ 
#  flt is a repeatable chunk so we create this part of the expression in a loop
#  all this really does is make the final datfmt regex seem shorter
flt     = '{}(?P<{}>([\d\.]+))'
args    = ('_fval', '\nentropy = _ent', '\nsamples = _samp', '%\nvalue = \[_lval', ', _rval')
fltreg  = ''.join([flt.format(a, b) for (a, b) in [arg.split('_') for arg in args]])

#regex to describe the data portion of an entry
datfmt  = re.compile('(?P<focus>([\w\d]+)) <= {}\]\nclass = (?P<class>(.+))'.format(fltreg), re.I|re.S)

#container for individual entries
entries = []

#entry descriptor
Entry   = namedtuple('Entry', 'x y focus fvalue entropy samples value cls')

#for storing entry index
c = 0

#find all entries
for m in entfmt.finditer(data):
    #consistent entry data
    x, y = float(m.group('x')), float(m.group('y'))
    #get all data for this entry
    m2 = datfmt.match(m.group('data'))
    #make sure this was not an empty entry
    if m2:
        #append entry
        entries.append(Entry(x, y,
                             m2.group('focus'), 
                             float(m2.group('fval')), 
                             float(m2.group('ent')), 
                             float(m2.group('samp')), 
                             [float(m2.group('lval')), float(m2.group('rval'))], 
                             m2.group('class')))
    else:
        #entry has empty data
        print('Data[{}] with [x:{}, y:{}] is empty'.format(c, x, y))
        
    #increment entry index
    c += 1
        
#print all entries
print(*entries, sep='\n')

#Entry(x=447.1153846153846 , y=471.625, focus='the'    , fvalue=0.5, entropy=0.97 , samples=100.0, value=[0.399, 0.601], cls='True News')
#Entry(x=238.46153846153845, y=336.875, focus='donald' , fvalue=0.5, entropy=0.921, samples=83.7 , value=[0.336, 0.664], cls='True News')
#Entry(x=119.23076923076923, y=202.125, focus='hillary', fvalue=0.5, entropy=0.981, samples=55.6 , value=[0.42 , 0.58 ], cls='True News')
#Entry(x=357.6923076923077 , y=202.125, focus='hillary', fvalue=0.5, entropy=0.663, samples=28.2 , value=[0.172, 0.828], cls='True News')
#Entry(x=655.7692307692307 , y=336.875, focus='trumps' , fvalue=0.5, entropy=0.859, samples=16.3 , value=[0.718, 0.282], cls='Fake News')
#Entry(x=596.1538461538462 , y=202.125, focus='hillary', fvalue=0.5, entropy=0.821, samples=15.7 , value=[0.744, 0.256], cls='Fake News')
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
import re

text = "[Text(447.1153846153846, 471.625, 'the <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.97\nsamples = 100.0%\nvalue = [0.399, " \
       "0.601]\nclass = True News'), Text(238.46153846153845, 336.875, 'donald <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.921\nsamples = " \
       "83.7%\nvalue = [0.336, 0.664]\nclass = True News'), Text(119.23076923076923, 202.125, 'hillary <= " \
       "0.5\nentropy = 0.981\nsamples = 55.6%\nvalue = [0.42, 0.58]\nclass = True News'), Text(59.61538461538461, " \
       "67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(178.84615384615384, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(357.6923076923077, 202.125, " \
       "'hillary <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.663\nsamples = 28.2%\nvalue = [0.172, 0.828]\nclass = True News'), " \
       "Text(298.0769230769231, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(417.30769230769226, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), " \
       "Text(655.7692307692307, 336.875, 'trumps <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.859\nsamples = 16.3%\nvalue = [0.718, " \
       "0.282]\nclass = Fake News'), Text(596.1538461538462, 202.125, 'hillary <= 0.5\nentropy = 0.821\nsamples = " \
       "15.7%\nvalue = [0.744, 0.256]\nclass = Fake News'), Text(536.5384615384615, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), " \
       "Text(655.7692307692307, 67.375, '\n (...) \n'), Text(715.3846153846154, 202.125, 'entropy = 0.0\nsamples = " \
       "0.6%\nvalue = [0.0, 1.0]\nclass = True News')] "

for match in re.finditer(", '(.*)?<=", text):
    print(match.group(1))
```

**Output**

```
the 
donald 
hillary 
hillary 
trumps 
hillary
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a look behind for the single quote `'` and a look ahead for `<=`
the middle non-quote characters can be matched for the content.

```
r"(?<=')[^']*?(?=\s*<=)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/KlYLQ2/1